# Why $(f(-x)) ^\prime=-f ^ \prime(-x)$?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Why this equaility holds $(f(-x)) ^\prime=-f ^ \prime(-x)$? I do not get it utterly.

Comment: you're right, this was not hard. I do not know why i did not get it, thank you

Comment: Being ambiguous, the notation $$(f(-x))'$$ should be discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) we have:
$$f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$
Set $g(x)=-x$. Then $g'(x)=-1$...